# Remove header row from CSV and write list of string to stream

Tags: c#

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\sample.csv"));
List<string> listA = new List<string>();
string line1;
Stream originalStream = null;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{                
    line1 = reader.ReadLine();
    listA.Add(line1);                
}
listA.RemoveAt(0);
originalStream = listA;
```

Here I am trying to remove first row and thats ok but after removing it I have other records in list of string which I want to write in a Stream variable.
can anybody tell me how can i achieve that.

Thanks

Comment: That looks incredibly inefficient, RemoveAt is O(n) operation. Instead of removing the header, just skip from adding it to the list in the first place. And why would you want a list of string as stream? What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Do you want to write this list to a memory stream or to another file?

Comment: another stream not file

Answer (score 3):

Reading all lines from file to a list and then removing one will not be fair, instead for whole those process i would like to suggest you a one liner like the following:

```
List<string> listA = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\sample.csv").Skip(1).ToList();
```

Use this lines to make Stream from List:

```
 var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
 Stream streamList = null;
 binFormatter.Serialize(streamList, listA);
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I am trying to build Biztalk pipeline component for that the output can only be in stream or streamreader as per my knowledge

Comment: is there a way to read the file in stream or streamreader and skip the first row(without list)

Comment: I had few updates to the answer, you can take a look

Comment: Hi I am getting below error   "The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: use `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;` to solve that error